# Определение вида сетевой связи в Android

Tags: android

Можно ли в Android каким-то образом определить, что используется для интернета (Wi-Fi, 3G, 4G, etc)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть еще более простой способ чем тот что я предложил в комментарии, и он описан в [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring):

```
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

Я думаю это будет самое простой решение вашей проблемы.